# Second derivative of the stress-energy tensor

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Which physical meaning can have if the second derivative of stress-energy tensor is zero? In General Relativity or elsewhere.

Comment: Second derivative with respect to what? Ordinary derivatives or covariant derivatives? The stress-energy tensor is covariantly conserved in GR: $\nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}=0$.

Comment: Dear Evan, thanks for your answer.. to me interest is for both  derivatives

Comment: can someone help me?